# discord.py running a 'commands.group()' sends the help command, when targeting second command

Tags: discord.py

Hard to get the title perfect, but pretty much. Got it hooked up that `!!changelog` is the main command, this will send a list of all the commands available, but issue I am getting is that. Whenever I run the `!!changelog message <text>` command, the preset "help" message shows up.

Picture here:
[image]

Whenever the message is sent, I just want it to say something like "Your message has been sent"

Here is my code:

```
@commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def changelog(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send('Available Setup Commands: \nSet Channel: <#channel>\nChangelog Message: <message>')

@changelog.command()
async def channel(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            f'SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}')
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            sql = ('INSERT INTO main(guild_id, channel_id) VALUES(?,?)')
            val = (ctx.guild.id, channel.id)
            await ctx.send(f'Channel has been set to {channel.mention}')
        elif result is not None:
            sql = ('UPDATE main SET channel_id = ? WHERE guild_id = ?')
            val = (channel.id, ctx.guild.id)
            await ctx.send(f'Channel has been updated to {channel.mention}')
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()

@changelog.command()
async def message(self, ctx, *, text):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
        est = timezone('EST')
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f'SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE 1')
        channel = cursor.fetchone()
        channel_id = self.client.get_channel(int(channel[0]))
        message = text.capitalize()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Changelog", description=f"● {message}", color=0)
        embed.set_footer(
            text=f'Published: {datetime.now(est).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}')
        await channel_id.send(embed=embed)
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ctx.invoked_subcommand` to check if you are running a subcommand in your group:

```
async def changelog(self, ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await ctx.send('Available Setup Commands: \nSet Channel <#channel>\nChangelog Message: <message>')
```